# Returning a custom exception

Tags: c#, exception

I am trying to implement my own Exception class in C#. For this purpose I have created a CustomException class derived from Exception.

```
class CustomException : Exception
{
    public CustomException()
        : base() { }

    public CustomException(string message)
        : base(message) { }

    public CustomException(string format, params object[] args)
        : base(string.Format(format, args)) { }

    public CustomException(string message, Exception innerException)
        : base(message, innerException) { }

    public CustomException(string format, Exception innerException, params object[] args)
        : base(string.Format(format, args), innerException) { }
}
```

Then I use it

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        var zero = 0;
        var s = 2 / zero;
    }
    catch (CustomException ex)
    {
        Console.Write("Exception");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

I'm expecting I will get my exception but all I get is a standard DivideByZeroException. How can I catch a divide by zero exception using my CustomException class? Thanks.

Comment: Why should  .NET  start to use your exception? You have to [`throw`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ah5wsex(v=vs.110).aspx) it yourself.

Comment: okay, even if I add throw new Exception to catch section I will not get it. I will continue to get standart exception. Do I need to write some code in my CustomException to catch DevideByZero Exceptions?

Comment: You should not if you throw _before_ the div by zero or use Alexei's approach. By the way: I think it is not good practice to replace exceptions unless you have very good reasons.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can't magically change type of exception thrown by existing code.

You need to `throw` your exception to be able to catch it:

```
try 
{
   try
    {
        var zero = 0;
        var s = 2 / zero;
    }
    catch (DivideByZeroException ex)
    { 
        // catch and convert exception
        throw new CustomException("Divide by Zero!!!!");
    }
}
catch (CustomException ex)
{
    Console.Write("Exception");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: You might want to mention that it's a horrible idea to do this.

Comment: @Wilbert which part? `2/zero` is probably easiest way to get very specific exception (`((string)(null)).Length` may look more obviously "sample code - don't copy"); re-throwing different exception is pretty standard practice when some high level operation fails due one of many different exception (`IOException`, `KeyNotFoundException` and like can be re-throw as `CustomerNotFoundException`, maybe with InnerException set to that exception, or maybe not due to security requirements); hopefully it is clear that nested `try`/`catch` is just a sample.

Comment: Yeah, with that context it makes sense, but just the code sample.. well :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov why standard exception dont need throw keyword??

Comment: @AminM - they are thrown, by existing code.  The reason you need to manually throw custom exceptions is because the custom exceptions don't have hooks in the framework (how could they?).  So you either throw them based on some logic in your method/function, or you throw them in lieu of a standard exception as in this example.

Answer (score 17):

First of all, if you want to see your own exception, you should `throw` it somewhere in your code:

```
public static int DivideBy(this int x, int y)
{
    if (y == 0)
    {
        throw new CustomException("divide by zero");
    }

   return x/y; 

}
```

then:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 0;
try
{
      a.DivideBy(b);
}
catch(CustomException)
{
//....
}
```