# Nhibernate data base independent error handling

Tags: c#, exception, nhibernate, error-handling

trying to find a solution for my last problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29539767/sql-nhibernate-exceptions-with-sqlite-and-c-sharp-and-known-error-codes), I decided to wrap all the exceptions with my own custom errors. Here my code so far:

```
    public Exception Convert(NHibernate.Exceptions.AdoExceptionContextInfo exInfo)
    {
        var sqle = (System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException)exInfo.SqlException;
        var errorDescription = exInfo.SqlException.Message.ToString();
        if (sqle != null)
        {
            //Definition of error codes (for SQLite) to catch and handle
            switch (sqle.ErrorCode)
            {
                //Most possible error in our project: case 19
                case 19:
                    return new ConstraintViolationException(exInfo.Message,
                        sqle.InnerException);
                case 5:
                    return new DbLockedException();
                case 6:
                    return new TableLockedException();
                case 8:
                    return new ReadOnlyDbException();
                case 9:
                    return new InterruptException();
                case 10:
                    return new IOException();
                case 11:
                    return new DbCorruptException();
```

And I followed the custom exception idea from here: [Returning a custom exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993003/custom-exception)

**Now I am facing a problem:**

As we are using NHibernate. We want to maintain our code data base independent. With the code that you can see, it would only work with SQLite.

- Does anyone know or have some idea on how could I manage errors to
  catch them no matter which DB I would use?

If you want to keep your program, DB independent, code Errors are not a good idea, because every DB has its own code errors and own exceptions.

Thanks for any heads up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encapsulated the database-dependent settings in dedicated assemblies:

- MyApplication.Data.SqlLite
- MyApplication.Data.Oracle

Each assembly contains a set of classes implementing common interface to put in a common assembly. In your case I would make an interface named `DbExceptionConverter` and the implmentation in their assemblies. In the start of application I would register in the container the right implementation.

You could also put them all in an abstract factory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It sounds very good, the approach that I was taking was a little bit complicated. I think this would be the best way. I was thinking in something like catching common exceptions and then make a translation, but I don't think that's as easy as it sounds.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what I in the end did is the following:

1- I left the ORM project intact as it doesn't really needs any specific DB reference or configurations (drivers, ...etc) (the assembly will know which driver to use by the hibernate.cfg.xml file)

2- as @onof sugested, I created a `DbExceptionConverter` assembly where I had all the database-dependent settings and the exceptions for each DB I wanted to use. Each class wraps the exceptions with their own codes.

The question that I had here was: "Now, how do I load the custom DbExceptionHandler?"
Well, I just use the `sql_exception_converter` property field in the "hibernate.cfg.xml" file as follows:

**For SQLite: (Note the sql_exception_converter property)**

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    <property name="adonet.batch_size">5000</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=DBFile.db;Version=3;New=True;UseUTF8Encoding=True;</property>
    <property name="sql_exception_converter">DbExceptionConverter.SQLiteExceptionHandler.SqlExceptionConverter, DbExceptionConverter</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**For Postgres: (Note the sql_exception_converter property)**

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.NpgsqlDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=DbName;User Id=postgres;Password=postgres;</property>
    <property name="sql_exception_converter">DbExceptionConverter.PostgresExceptionHandler.SqlExceptionConverter, DbExceptionConverter</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

3- In each sql_exception_converter property, you can see that I used the namespace of the class and the class name to tell the assembly which exception handler to use.

It turned out to be very easy and I hope I can help someone else out with my experience with this.

If someone has any ideas, suggestions, or think that this is not such a good idea, I will be happy to hear it.